# 20.04 No way to access the internet

Tags: gnome, 20.04, internet, ethernet, ubuntu-gnome

I have upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 from the Ubuntu software updater. When I restarted, 20.04 said there is no wifi or Bluetooth adapter. This was a common problem on 18.04, which used to be sorted on a reboot. But now that's not happening.

Most of the solutions appear to involve an installing of some drivers by connecting to the internet in some other way, say, Ethernet or tethering. But unfortunately, those are also not working for me.

I have another wifi adapter with me. I connected it to the pc, but that is also not recognised.

So practically there is no way to access the internet.

Any idea why this is happening?

Edit: I just noticed, if I boot in recovery mode, I'm getting the internet.

Comment: You can access the internet using a phone connected to a USB port in most of cases. Regarding what is the problem there is no information to tell anything.

Comment: @Pilot6 No. I tried usb tethering. It's not working. The settings show no adapter found and there is no wired connection option.

Comment: @Pilot6 But if I boot in recovery mode and resume normal boot from there, I'm getting them all.

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Replace "`-b 0`" with "`-b -1`","`-b  -2`", etc to look at earlier boots. Read `man journalctl`. Compare `lsmod` output in both normal and recovery boots.